# Execute ffmpeg command with C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

Hi can someone show me how you would execute the following command against FFmpeg in C#.

```
mkfifo temp1.a
mkfifo temp1.v
mkfifo temp2.a
mkfifo temp2.v
mkfifo all.a
mkfifo all.v
ffmpeg -i input1.flv -vn -f u16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 44100 - > temp1.a < /dev/null &
ffmpeg -i input2.flv -vn -f u16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 44100 - > temp2.a < /dev/null &
ffmpeg -i input1.flv -an -f yuv4mpegpipe - > temp1.v < /dev/null &
{ ffmpeg -i input2.flv -an -f yuv4mpegpipe - < /dev/null | tail -n +2 > temp2.v ; } &
cat temp1.a temp2.a > all.a &
cat temp1.v temp2.v > all.v &
ffmpeg -f u16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 44100 -i all.a \
       -f yuv4mpegpipe -i all.v \
       -sameq -y output.flv
rm temp[12].[av] all.[av]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Process.Start` method from `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for getting back to me. I know how to execute the the exe file. The problem i have is that I dont understand how to execute the commands, do you execute it as 1 argument to the exe file or do split up the arguments and call the exe multiple times. That is what i am stuck on.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the executable files of `ffmpeg` from the official site and place them in your application startup path and then eecute them using the `Process.Start()` and after then pass on the arguments to that according to your needs.

Example:-

**exe path-**
    ffprobe.exe -hide_banner -show_format -show_streams -pretty {video_file}

```
private static string Execute(string exePath, string parameters)
{
string result = String.Empty;

using (Process p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = parameters;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();

    result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}

return result;
}
```